# Error using containers.Map/values The specified key is not present in this container

Tags: matlab, error-handling

First, here is the command that produces the error: `ZZ = values(mapZ,T.pol);`

In my understanding, the error occurs because there is an element in T.pol, which is not a key in mapZ. Is this correct?

I would like to handle this error by outputting an empty cell or '' when a key is not found. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of an answer:

```
function result = revisedvalues(map,keys)

result = cell(size(keys,1),1);

for i = 1:size(keys,1)

    if isKey(map,keys(i))
        result(i)= values(map,keys(i));
    else
        result(i)= [];
    end

end


end
```

This seems to be working with my data. Any comments?